# What is the meaning of "bi masabiha" in surah 67:5

Tags: tafseer, quran-translation, arabic-translation

I have read on many websites that shooting star is meteor in science,
but I read the translation of the quran in surah Al-Mulk ayat 5 that :

> And We have certainly beautified the nearest heaven with **stars** and have made [from] **them** what is thrown at the devils and have prepared for them the punishment of the Blaze.

is this somekind of error in translation? because in science star is sun. not meteor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

maṣābīḥ is the plural of miṣbāḥ, which means “lamp, light”. Of course, the commentators have debated what sort of “lamps” are intended in this verse, but one view is that the reference is to meteors or some other shooting stars. In any case maṣābīḥ in the plural can hardly refer to the sun.

Comment: where can I learned the word of arabic translated in english? so I can get the reference, thanks

Comment: The first place to look is a good dictionary. There are several here: http://ejtaal.net/

Comment: I visit the website, but I can't hardly understand it, I''l accept your answer if you give the reference on the book or website. thanks for your answer and sharing knowledge.

Comment: Or this: http://ejtaal.net/aa/#hw4=598,ll=1687,ls=5,la=2388,sg=590,ha=399,br=533,pr=89,vi=218,mgf=498,mr=355,mn=760,aan=322,kz=1313,uqq=186,ulq=1058,uqa=233,uqw=910,umr=593,ums=500,umj=444,bdw=511,amr=358,asb=532,auh=866,dhq=305,mht=500,msb=133,tla=65,amj=434,ens=906,mis=1188

Comment: Thank you for your reference. Now I understand the miracale of The Quran

Comment: wel I can conclude that the translation of the quran right now has to be changed because it will confused the reader or someone who doesn't understand

Comment: Every translation is different. The best ones are those that adhere most closely to the literal meaning of the words.

Comment: @aasheq, well done, your response deserves +1vote, as a nice brief answer. Good luck mate.